# Usb tethering with linux and htc desire s other than rndis_host

Tags: linux, networking, ip, android

I want to share the connection of my htc desire s with linux and I'm doing it but if it is possibile I'd like to avoid using the `rndis_host` module. The tethering can be configured as "windows" or "mac osx" and actually it is set to "windows".

Can I set it to "mac osx" and use more standard protocol? Which module should I enable in the kernel?